# What to do with duplicate questions

Tags: support

Today a question appeared which was answered already quite some time ago in another question, very clean and well put.

**The New Question**

[Using a variable in dynamic sql](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9339/using-a-variable-in-dynamic-sql)

**The Old**

[Elegant way to convert Set<Id> into String for Dynamic SOQL IN comparison](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3526/elegant-way-to-convert-setid-into-string-for-dynamic-soql-in-comparison/3527#3527)

What should we do? Close the new and refer to the old?

*I really hope this isn't a duplicate question on Meta, else i'll look like a total ass*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By clicking on Close, I actually already answered my question.

[image]

Comment: Bingo — If you do this then the mods see flags in their top bar upon logging in, if the question's not yet received enough such flags from users to close it we can just close it off ourselves.